# Storing many text files with large similarities

Tags: web-scraping, compression, storage, object-storage

I need to store millions of HTML files, each around 100kB (30kB gzipped). These files belong to a handful of groups. Files in each group have large similar chunks.

I would like to store these files compactly (much better than individual gzip) and retrieve them by key. I would insert new files over time, including ones with new structure. I'm not interested in searching the files.

Is there an existing solution for storing these files? For example a specialized service on top of an object store.

What are possible approaches for a custom solution? I'm considering storing files in gzipped groups of 1000 and maintaining an index in a database.

Edit: I would be continuously adding files. I would also like to stream out all the files in insertion order every few weeks.

Comment: While a well written problem statement and an interesting problem, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter The "custom solution" part does fall under "a specific programming problem" in my opinion. In a sense I am asking about a good on-disk data structure for my use case. The "existing solution" question is to avoid reinventing the wheel, in case there is some generic solution that I missed in my searches, but I doubt there is. I think moving to softwarerecs won't get it answered. Is there a way to edit the question to be more appropriate for SO?

Comment: As no one else has voted to close, maybe you'll get a good answer here. I have a text book about search engine technology that covered issues similar to this, but it is away in a box. If I can find it and there is anything of use there, I'll let  you know what I find. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to access individual files on a regular basis here's what you can do:

Create an "offset lookup" file that lists your file names and sizes. Concatenate all your files into a humongous huge.txt file. Zip huge.txt and store it alongside with lookup.txt

In the rare even of needing one of the files, unzip huge.txt, use lookup.txt to find where inside your huge.txt your file starts and how many bytes it has, and extract it from there.

Comment: I actually need to stream all the files in insertion order every few weeks. I'll add that to the question. You could combine your approach  with mine and split the zips by time ("groups of 1000") - that would make streaming acceptable performance-wise. I'd like to see if there's a better approach than this though.

Comment: Actually, one big zip would work in terms of streaming out, but would be bad for adding new files.

Comment: How does `tar` works for you? Maybe `tar -cfz` would be enough.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, since some kind of zip with an index is probably the most reasonable solution for this general problem (good enough results with relatively little effort). In my case, I'm going to try a domain-specific approach using diffs to speed up later parsing, then fall back to zips if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly, outside the box answer: put the files in a git repository. Apparently, it compresses large chunks of similar bytes together.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've done something similar myself. Pick some random chunks of file A, find them in every other file B and widen them as long as both files match. This covers ~90% of the file. Gzipping what remains (single file) is ~2kB. This together with the grouped zip approach should do quite well.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to concatenate your groups of a thousand files into a single file for gzipping, which should take advantage of the common blocks, if they are within 32K bytes distance from each other in the concatenation. You could also try [zstd](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/) which has much larger dictionary sizes, and would surely be able to take advantage of the common blocks.

You can look at [gzlog](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) for rapid appending of new data to a gzip stream.